# O que é Computação Móvel e Ubíqua?

Tags: terminologia

- O que significa Computação Móvel e Ubíqua?
- Quais suas principais características?
- Quais as principais áreas de aplicação?

Comment: Já procurou por "Internet das coisas"? Ou "Internet of things"/IoT? Creio que isso pode te ajudar em computação ubíqua

Comment: Murilo, as respostas abaixo te atendeu ou precisa de mais alguma informação?!

Answer (score 4):

A ideia principal da computação móvel é a de que o seu dispositivo está sempre em movimento, você pode usa-lo em praticamente qualquer lugar que você esteja. Este conceito se difundiu muito devido a aparição dos smartphones e dos avanços computacionais que permitiram que os dispositivos ficassem cada vez menores.

Já a computação ubíqua é definido como a computação quase que onipresente no cotidiano das pessoas, atualmente quase tudo se faz uso de um computador, seja do seu relógio até a geladeira de sua casa, praticamente tudo você encontra um computador, ou seja, Computação Ubíqua é a computação presente em tudo, Computação Móvel é a computação que você pode usa-la em qualquer lugar.

Espero ter ajudado :D

Answer (score 1):

Talvez tenha esquecido de citar também a **Computação Pervasiva**, no qual facilita para obter um melhor entendimento.

A **Computação Móvel** é um termo mais popular, por fazer parte com mais frequência do nosso cotidiano. Pode ser compreendida como o acesso a informação em qualquer lugar, a qualquer momento, e para que isso aconteça
há uma diversidade de equipamentos como os celulares, tablets, PDAS, etc.

O conceito de **Computação Pervasiva** implica que os meios de computação estão distribuídos no ambiente de forma perceptível e imperceptível ao usuário. Basicamente a Computação Pervasiva é o que a define como invisível ao olho nu, mas sabe-se que ela está presente no espaço.

Como se pode observar na figura abaixo, a fusão dessas tecnologias resulta na **Computação Ubíqua** que possui como suas principais características a **descentralização**, **diversidade** e a **conectividade**. Basicamente surge da integração da mobilidade com a presença distribuída, imperceptível, inteligente e altamente integrada de computadores e suas aplicações.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Quais as principais áreas de aplicação?

Na educação, na medicina, nas residências, etc.

Referência

- [Sistemas de Informação Distribuídos/Computação Ubíqua nos Sistemas de Informação Distribuídos](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Sistemas_de_Informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_Distribu%C3%ADdos/Computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_Ub%C3%ADqua_nos_Sistemas_de_Informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_Distribu%C3%ADdos)